# How to configure existing project to use polymer dart 1.0.0-rc.2?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I created new polymer dart project with dependences:

```
dependencies:
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.2
  web_components: ^0.12.0
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.1
  browser: ^0.10.0
  reflectable: ^0.3.1
dependency_overrides:
  polymer_interop:
    git:
      ref: 0.2.0-rc1
      url: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_interop.git
```

and everything worked fine (I can create new dom-module and use polymer elements). But then I tried to use exactly the same dependency configuration in existing project and when I run `pub get` I get:

```
Package reflectable has no versions that match >=0.3.1 <0.4.0 derived from:
- fbnn depends on version ^0.3.1
- polymer 1.0.0-rc.2 depends on version ^0.3.1
- polymer_elements 1.0.0-rc.1 depends on version ^0.3.1
```

I also try to do `pub cache repair` but it didn't help. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you have an SDK constraint in the existing project? Have you tried without the `dependency_overrides`?

Comment: You can also try pubviz to see your package dependencies and what might be holding you back, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pubviz

Comment: The SDK is constrained to `sdk: '>=1.8.0 <2.0.0'` and yes, I have tried removing `dependency_overrides` with no effect.

Comment: `pubviz open` on the fresh project shows me nice graph, but when I run it on my existing project it throws exception `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'isPrimary='` (here is stacktrace: http://pastebin.ca/3185690). But thanks, I don't know about pubviz - looks like quite useful tool.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution by removing random combination of dependencies. It appears that I have to remove `dartson: any` so `pub get` finally starts working. I don't know why `pub get` returns such unrelated output.

Comment: That's a know issue with `pub get`. You can try `pub get --verbose` to get more details.